# Best way to remove duplicates in a table while filtered for values from another table

Tags: sql, join, window-functions

i have 2 table `traffic` and `orders`. I want to select only the orders that were placed within 30 days since traffic timestamp of the same customer. How can i efficiently do that?

**Order table**

| order_date | order_id | customer | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 March 22 | A | X | 5 |
| 2 May 22 | B | X | 10 |

**Traffic table**

| timestamp | customer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Jan 22 | X |
| 28 Feb 22 | X |
| 1 Mar 22 | X |
| 4 May 22 | X |

The result i want is: Total order value = 5. Because:

- The order was placed within 30 days since traffic timestamp (both 28 Feb and 1 Mar satisfied the filter condition)
- Order B is excluded because it's not within 30 days since any timestamp in the traffic table (it exceeded 30 days since 1 Mar and was before 4 May)

Both tables are **very large** so i don't think select distinct from an inner join will do.
I'm thinking of a window function over the union of both tables and do a last_value of timestamp over the same customer but i'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve what i want.

**Solution 1** i don't want the distinct in here

```sql
select sum(value) from 
(select distinct order_date, order_id, customer, value 
from order o
inner join traffic t on o.customer_id = t.customer_id 
and o.order_date >= t.timestamp
and o.order_date <= date_add('day',30,t.timestamp)
```

**solution 2**: seems overkill?

```
with temp as (
select *, null as last_traffic  
from order
union 
select timestamp as report_date, null as order_id, customer, null as value, timestamp as traffic_date from traffic 
),

temp2 as 
(
select *,
last_value(traffic_date ignore nulls) over (partition by customer_id order by report_date rows unbounded preceding) as last_traffic
from temp
)

select sum(value) from temp2 where report_date >= last_traffic
and report_date <= date_add('day',30,last_traffic)
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `Order` and `Traffic`? I see a common field - `customer`, but this seems to have nothing to do with your description of wanting to get "orders placed since traffic timestamp"? How you do know if an order is "placed since traffic timestamp"? Which traffic timestamp?

Comment: the relationship is same customer & order timestamp within 30 days since traffic timestamp

Comment: you have two timestamps (as far as I know you could have hundreds of them). You want results for each timestamp (as many as there are)? In any case, perhaps you need a little more data to show what you want and what kind of data you are working with? This is not really enough data to demonstrate a desired result. Again, *how do you decide what timestamp to use in regard to "its" orders*?

Comment: Also, for what its worth - first, just write your query and later on you can worry about optimizing it. At this point, we need to know what the query is before we decide if it can be optimized ... true that you might be able to write a better performing query from the start if you are thinking that way, but still the first step is to have a query, and probably better not to do things to it just for the sake of optimization on the first go (of course you might still want to avoid correlated subqueries and calling scalar functions in where clauses and other "smells"...).

Comment: Another quick comment - please define "within 30 days". Does that mean 15 days before and 15 days after, or 30 days after, or 30 days before, or 30 days before and 30 days after .... or all of those all at once (haha bad joke - gandalf/bilbo)

Comment: The best performing query, given appropriate index, would be a semi-join using an `exists` criteria.

Comment: i don't think i can use exists here because it's filtering for a time range, not a specific value?

Comment: Of course you can - bot exactly how depends on your RDBMS, which we don't know you have not [tagged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) it

Comment: @Dan Pham I think you have answered your own questions basically. You have two (now three) queries to try. It is hard for anyone to say which is best without seeing the execution strategy that is chosen by the DB Engine (MySQL?). But you should try them and see which performs best. I think your solution one is easiest to understand and looks correct so you could probably use it as a benchmark, then see if solution 2 (or answers below) do better or not...

Comment: FWIW, on a very small dataset, the *exists* (below) does come out fastest by a good margin, with the other two being about the same ... but I don't always trust results that come off of very small datasets since a lot can be forgiven when you only have 10 rows to worry about in your tables).

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I've interpereted your date requirement correctly, does the following *exists* criteria (untested of course) work for you?

```
select Value 
from orders o
where exists (
    select *
    from traffic t
    where t.customer = o.customer
      and t.timestamp <= o.order_date 
      and t.timestamp >= Date_Add('day', -30, o.order_date)
);
```

Comment: thanks for helping! it's a new way to me! however looks like it is also as costly as the distinct from inner join method. my tables are huge so it's not ideal using the both approaches